# Microsoft Access: How to autofill every record in a field in a table?

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm working with 2 existing tables.

The primary table (`Table1`) has thousands of existing records and I need to add a field with data (`State`) and autogenerate the entry for every record at the same time, based on the data in another column (`Color`) with existing data within this table, and based on another reference table (`Table2`).

How do I make this reference and automatically fill all fields in the new `State` column?

[image: Example here]

All answers I can find relate to autofill with forms, which I am not working with.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the `State` field to your `Table1`, you can run a simple `update` query such as the following to populate it with the appropriate data:

```
update Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.Color = Table2.Color
set Table1.State = Table2.State
```